# How to fetch the Backend data in front end multi select drop down (or) multi select formatter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, c#-4.0

```
loadComplete: function () {
var ids = jQuery("#getFulldataGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    var cl = ids[i];
    var rowdata = jQuery("#getFulldataGrid").jqGrid('getRowData', cl);
    var pid = rowdata.ProductID;
    var signid = rowdata.SignTypeID;

    FillProduct(ids[i], pid);
    FillSignType(ids[i], signid);

    $("#ddlProductType" + ids[i]).multiselect({
        multiple: true,
        noneSelectedText: "Select",
        selectedList: 0,
        minWidth: 145
    });
}

//Product Formatter
function ProductName(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var MDB = '<select id="ddlProductType' + options.rowId + '" multiple="multiple" style="width: 150px"></select>'
    return MDB;
}

function FillProduct(id, x) {
    PageMethods.FillProduct(onSucess, onFailure)
    function onSucess(r) {
        jQuery('#ddlProductType option').remove();
        $.each(r, function (index, data) {
            $('#ddlProductType' + id + '').append('<option value="' + data.ID_Proof + '">' + data.Id_Proof_Name + '</option>').multiselect('refresh');
            $("#ddlProductType").multiselect('refresh');
        });
    }
    function onFailure(r) {
        alert(r._message);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here I saved the details in sql server via front end and saved successfully in sql. After saving when I reload the jqgrid in front end I want to fetch the details in multi select dropdown like what I saved before in sql.

Other details are fetching successfully in single dropdown. Above I drop a LoadComplete function and Formatter of that dropdown function. Please help me

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: When i reload the grid, data did not fetching. But data already saved in database. single drop down data is fetching successfully. But Multi select drop down didn't. please help me

Comment: Any one can help me

Comment: I think the the refresh method should be called only once after all inserted data and there is no need to refresh it at every step in onSucess function.I think that your logic is not correct. In loadComplete you call FillProduct, which updates multiselect and after that you  create it again

Comment: How to re create , can you please explain